# ACCESS - how to store single space as cell value

Tags: ms-access

In Acess 2007, we need to store the value of "space" into a cell for testing purposes. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't have Access to test, but if you're doing it via SQL, wouldn't it just be ' '?

Comment: Hmm...I hadn't thought of trying to write via SQL - so far we've just been using the Access program. (And, admittedly I'm new to using Access)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to update the data from a query or through code because the datasheet view trims trailing spaces

```
   UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.Foo = " "
   WHERE (((Table1.ID)=1));
```

then this will return results later.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Foo
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Foo)=" "));
```

Comment: I've tried using the space bar for data entry, but unless the space is followed by a non-space character, it isn't being stored.

Comment: Sorry about that I made a mistake on my results. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! - we'll give it a shot after this meeting

Comment: Is it possible for this to be explained better?

Comment: @AChildOfGod which part?

Comment: @ConradFrix the code, where it goes, what it does, what parts of it are interchangeable depending on the names of the table. I personally am new to Access and have a lot to learn.